# Set the current item of a spinner when refreshed

Tags: android, spinner, refresh

I'm currently working on an android project and I'm having a problem.
I want the spinner selects the current item after refreshed. Instead, it shows the default item, which is at index 0. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```java
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    populateSpinner();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Items selectedItem = (Items) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    itemList.clear();
    spinner.setSelection(position);

    if (position == 0) {
        loadItems();
    } else {
        loadItemsByLocation(selectedItem);
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

Comment: before refreshing save the index of selected spinner item . and in refresh method just set the spinner item like that mySpinner.setSelection(index);

Comment: @HasnainSabir that worked really well, thanks!